# Helper object is not updating the target position

Tags: javascript, three.js, lighting

My scene has a cube and a directional light with your Helper. 
The cube is placed on X: 300 Y: 100 z: 0 and the light is positioned at X: 300 Y: 600 z: 0. 
The Target object of light has the same position of the cube.

But the target of the helper is being drawn at (0, 0, 0).

How do I make drawing Helper point to the target light?

This is my code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube.position.set(300, 100, 0);

scene.add(cube);

var color = 0xffffff;
var intensity = 1;

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( color, intensity );     
light.position.set(300, 600, 0);

light.target.position.set(300, 100, 0);

scene.add( light );

var helper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper( light, 20 );
scene.add( helper );
helper.update();
```

Comment: Did you call update() on the helper?

Comment: Yes I'm calling. 
Apparently the problem is that the position of the target is not updated in MatrixWorld the target object.